# New Users and Mailbox from Hashtable

Tags: powershell, scripting

As I mentioned in my last question, I'm new to PowerShell and have pieced together a bit of Frankenstein script for creating new users. It works fine for creating users (using new-aduser), but when I attempt to add the 'new-mailbox' cmdlet, it creates a 'sytems.collections.hashtable' is created and the script errors out. I presume it has to do with the mailbox cmdlet not handling the hashtable.. Is there a way to pass the hashtable to new-mailbox and pipe to set-aduser, or am I attempting something that can't be done? Is there an easier way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? I'm currently using Powershell ISE with a pssession to my Exchange server. Any advice/tips/criticism is welcome and much appreciated.

```
Function Provision { PROCESS { CreateUser $_ } }

Function ProvisionInputCSV {
Param ([string]$filename)
$users = Import-CSV $filename
foreach ($user in $users) {
$ht = @{'givenName'=$user."First Name";
        'sn'= $user."Last Name";
        'displayName'= $user."Last Name" + " ," + " " + $user."First Name";
        'samAccountName'= $user."Logon Name";
        'title'= $user."title";
        'description'= $user."Description";
        'department'= $user."Department";
        'company'= $user."Company";
        'password'= ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $user.Password -force;
        'userprincipalname'= $user.userprincipalname;
        'employeeid'= $user.employeeid

       }
Write-Output $ht
}
}            

Function CreateUser { Param($user) New-Mailbox $user -Database "StaffDB1" -alias     $user.samaccountname -password $user.password -UserPrincipalName $user.userprincipalname -OrganizationalUnit "ou=users,dc=mydomain,DC=com" -ResetPasswordOnNextLogon $true -DisplayName $user.displayname | Set-Mailbox -CustomAttribute5 "AA" | Set-ADUser -GivenName $user.givenname -Surname $user.surname -DisplayName $user.displayname -EmployeeID $user.employeeid -Description $user.description -Department $user.department -Company $user.company -UserPrincipalName $user.userprincipalname -Enabled $true}

ProvisionInputCSV c:\users\newusers.csv | Provision
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after reviewing my code and playing around with set-aduser, new-mailbox, set-mailbox, etc., I was finally able to solve my problem - creating a new user with specific AD attributes and mail-enabling it. Below is my final code that appears to be working thus far for anyone who is interested.. Thanks also to Patrick for help on the second bit.

```
#Create New User Accounts

Function Provision { PROCESS { CreateUser $_ } }

Function ProvisionInputCSV {
Param ([string]$filename)
$users = Import-CSV $filename
foreach ($user in $users) {
$ht = @{'givenName'=$user."First Name";
        'sn'= $user."Last Name";
        'displayName'= $user."Last Name" + " ," + " " + $user."First Name";
        'samAccountName'= $user."Logon Name";
        'title'= $user."title";
        'description'= $user."Description";
        'department'= $user."Department";
        'company'= $user."Company";
        'password'= ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $user.Password -force;
        'upn'= $user.userprincipalname;
        'employeeid'= $user.employeeid

       }
 Write-Output $ht
 }
}            

Function CreateUser { Param($user) New-ADUser –name ($user['sn'] + ',' + ' ' + $user['givenname']) -givenname $user.givenname -surname $user.sn -DisplayName $user.displayname -SamAccountName $user.samaccountname -UserPrincipalName $user.upn -employeeid $user.employeeid -Description $user.description -title $user.title -Department $user.department -Company $user.company -accountpassword $user.password -path 'ou=Students,ou=Business Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com' -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -enabled $true}


ProvisionInputCSV c:\filepath\newusers.csv | Provision


#Enable mailboxes for Existing Users

$Mailboxes = Import-CSV c:\filepath\newusers.csv

ForEach ($Mailbox In $Mailboxes) { Enable-Mailbox -identity ($mailbox."Logon Name") -DisplayName ($Mailbox."Last Name" + " ," + " " + $Mailbox."First Name") -Database "MyDB1" -alias ($mailbox."Logon Name") | Set-Mailbox -CustomAttribute5 "AA" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a hash table and pass this with the pipe to the command. But in the command you use not the propertys from the hash table ($_.givenname), you use the data propertys from the csv ($user.givenname). I think this is one ishue. Can you try this snippet? I splited the code.

```
$users = Import-CSV $filename
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $ht = @{
        'givenName'=$user."First Name";
        'sn'= $user."Last Name";
        'displayName'= $user."Last Name" + " ," + " " + $user."First Name";
        'samAccountName'= $user."Logon Name";
        'title'= $user."title";
        'description'= $user."Description";
        'department'= $user."Department";
        'company'= $user."Company";
        'password'= ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $user.Password -force;
        'userprincipalname'= $user.userprincipalname;
        'employeeid'= $user.employeeid
    }

    #Do exchange things
    New-Mailbox -Database "StaffDB1" -alias $ht.samaccountname -password $ht.password -UserPrincipalName $ht.userprincipalname`
        -OrganizationalUnit "ou=users,dc=mydomain,DC=com" -ResetPasswordOnNextLogon $true -DisplayName $ht.displayname | Set-Mailbox -CustomAttribute5 "AA"

    #Do ad things
    Set-ADUser -GivenName $ht.givenname -Surname $ht.surname -DisplayName $ht.displayname`
        -EmployeeID $ht.employeeid -Description $ht.description -Department $ht.department -Company $ht.company -UserPrincipalName $ht.userprincipalname -Enabled $true

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Patrick. I got the original code to work setting the -Name property for New-Mailbox (in the original code I just used the $user variable). The mailbox is created, the custom attribute set, but it skips set-aduser. Also, I need to be able to set AD attributes like 'EmployeeID' at the time of creation which Set-Aduser doesn't allow. Do you know if there's a way to pipe new-aduser to new-mailbox?